# SwiftData relations

Tags: swift, swift-data

I'm I'm playing with the new swiftData I'm try to understand how the relations work my happy to have to model class:

Each Flight on my APP contained many crews, I wrote the relation like in the following code but keep getting the error " Fatal error: Inverse Relationship does not exist"

How should we write this relation:

```
@Model
class Flight {
    @Attribute(.unique) var flightID: UUID
    var typeOfFlight: String
    var flightDateUTC : Date
    var flightNumber: String?
    
    @Relationship(.cascade) var flightData: FlightData
    @Relationship(.cascade) var flightTime : FlightTime
    @Relationship(.noAction) var aircraft : Aircraft?
    @Relationship(inverse: \CrewModel.name)
    var crews : [CrewModel]? //<-------------------------------
    
    init(flightID: UUID, typeOfFlight: String, flightDateUTC: Date, flightNumber: String? = nil, flightData: FlightData, flightTime: FlightTime, aircraft: Aircraft? = nil, crews: [CrewModel]? = nil) {
        self.flightID = flightID
        self.typeOfFlight = typeOfFlight
        self.flightDateUTC = flightDateUTC
        self.flightNumber = flightNumber
        self.flightData = flightData
        self.flightTime = flightTime
        self.aircraft = aircraft
        self.crews = crews
    }
}


@Model
class CrewModel{
    
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Relationship(.noAction, inverse: \Flight.flightID)
    var name : String?
    var crewID: String?
    var company: String?
    var isMe: Int?
    var email: String?
    var phone: String?
    var score: Int?
    var isPIC: Int?
    var isSIC: Int?
    var dataImage: Data?
    var comment: String?
    
    init(id: UUID, name: String? = nil, crewID: String? = nil, company: String? = nil, isMe: Int? = nil, email: String? = nil, phone: String? = nil, score: Int? = nil, isPIC: Int? = nil, isSIC: Int? = nil, dataImage: Data? = nil, comment: String? = nil) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.crewID = crewID
        self.company = company
        self.isMe = isMe
        self.email = email
        self.phone = phone
        self.score = score
        self.isPIC = isPIC
        self.isSIC = isSIC
        self.dataImage = dataImage
        self.comment = comment
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using the `inverse` parameter you only need to define the relationship in one of the model types. The value for `inverse` must point to a property of the type of the model.

in `Flight`

```
@Relationship(inverse: \CrewModel.flight) var crews : [CrewModel]?
```

and in `CrewModel`

```
var flight: Flight?
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Joakim’s answer, you shouldn’t be dealing with an optional array. It makes sense if you think of the scenario where no crew is assigned to a specific `Flight`, the array is going to be empty, not missing.

You should change it to the following for this reason:

```swift
@Relationship(inverse: \CrewModel.flight) var crews = [CrewModel]()
```

Also I’m creating an empty array at the model’s initialization, because you’re more likely to run into issues if you’re trying to insert a new `Flight` that already has references to other `CrewModel`s, over simply creating the `Flight`, inserting it into SwiftData, and then appending `CrewModel`s to it.